# Pythonic way of making combinations in groups

Tags: python, arrays, loops

Given I have the following list:

| group | code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 7 |

How do I create the following list in a pythonic way?:

| group | code | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| A | 2 | 3 |
| B | 4 | 5 |
| B | 4 | 6 |
| B | 4 | 7 |
| B | 5 | 6 |
| B | 5 | 7 |
| B | 6 | 7 |

I saw from another ticket that suggests using itertools import combinations.  But how to get by the grouping restriction:  I don't want all matches, just ones within groups.

Comment: You say "list", but you're showing a table. What actual Python data structure are you working with? Please [edit] a [mre] into your question.

Comment: are you able to use `pandas` lib?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use itertool to get combinations all possible code combinations for each group

```py
from itertools import combinations
A = [1,2,3] 
B = [4,5,6,7]

comb_A = combinations(A, 2)
comb_B = combinations(B, 2)

#to see the results iterate through all the combinations
# For A (the same applies for B)
for comb in comb_A:
    print(comb)
>>> (1,2)
>>> (1,3)
>>> (2,3)
```

Note: It will be more helpful if you could provide the "list" so we can give a more specific answer

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't post a MWE of what you tried, I'll show you steps that you can implement yourself.

1. Build a dictionary of data groups, say `group_dict`.
2. Create an empty list for `result`.
3. Iterate through the items in `group_dict`, where each item is a group name and a list of codes for that group.
4. For each group, use the `combinations` function to generate all possible combinations of 2 codes.
5. For each combination, append a tuple of the group name, the first code, and the second code to `result`.

This should give you a result like this:

```
[('A', 1, 2), ('A', 1, 3), ('A', 2, 3), ('B', 4, 5), ('B', 4, 6), ('B', 4, 7), ('B', 5, 6), ('B', 5, 7), ('B', 6, 7)]
```